# How to pass derived classes to same function with same signature in c#?

Tags: c#, function, inheritance

I am trying to pass multiple classes derived from one base class, to the same method. How can I achieve this without adding parameters to a function?

I have a base class:

```
public class SmartSuggestionRule
```

And then I have multiple derived classes:

```
public class Sample1SmartSuggestionRule : SmartSuggestionRule
public class Sample2SmartSuggestionRule : SmartSuggestionRule
```

I have this function which is using the properties of BaseClass only:

```
private List<SmartSuggestionRule> MatchKeywordToRule(
  ref string keywords,
  List<SmartSuggestionRule> rules)
```

how can I pass Sample1SmartSuggestionRule and Sample2SmartSuggestionRule to this function without adding more parameters?

```
private IEnumerable<SmartSuggestionRule> MatchKeywordToRule(ref string keywords, IEnumerable<SmartSuggestionRule> rules)
{
    var result = new List<SmartSuggestionRule>();

    foreach (var rule in rules)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rule.KeywordRules))
            continue;
        var descriptionRules = rule.KeywordRules
            .Replace("-", " ")
            .Split(new[] { " | ", "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var isMatch = HandleSolrBasedMatching(descriptionRules, ref keywords);

        if (isMatch)
        {
            result.Add(rule);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

(the function details)

Comment: How about adding them to the `rules` parameter?

Comment: Is your problem actually that you can't convert a `List<Sample1SmartSuggestionRule>` to a `List<SmartSuggestionRule>`?

Comment: Can't you use a generic method?

Comment: you can say that. I tried implicit conversion (List<SmartSuggestionRule>)Sample1SmartSuggestionRule but it doesn't work

Comment: If you are not manipulating the list, you could change the parameter type from `List<SmartSuggestionRule>` to `IEnumerable<SmartSuggestionRule>`. This allows you to pass any collection of SmartSuggestionRule and derived classes.

Comment: @shingo MatchKeywordToRule was intended to be a generic method though. didn't get your point....

Comment: @KlausGütter your suggestion worked! I had to do some implicit conversion, which I was not doing correctly.
`(List<Sample1SmartSuggestionRule>)MatchKeywordToRule(ref keywordsInput, sample1SmartSuggestionRuleObj);`

Comment: Was? Why isn't it generic now?

Comment: @shingo it is generic actually. I added the function definition above in my question as well. I am only changing base class properties. IEnumerable worked like a charm in my case.

Comment: ...It isn't, a generic method should be `private List<T> MatchKeywordToRule<T>(ref string keywords, List<T> rules) where T : SmartSuggestionRule`

Comment: ohh, this works!! I updated the List<SmartSuggestionRule> to IEnumerable<SmartSuggestionRule>, which caused me to implicitly convert the list to derived class list. this generic method approach is better I believe! I'll compare the perfomance now in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you could pass to `rules` parameter a base class list containing derived class objects:

```
var miscrules = new List<SmartSuggestionRule>();
miscrules.Add(new Sample1SmartSuggestionRule(){...});
miscrules.Add(new Sample2SmartSuggestionRule(){...});

var matched = MatchKeywordToRule(keywords, miscrules);
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is, I don't have the list `Sample2SmartSuggestion` in the beginning. The results from `Sample1SmartSuggestion` will be checked first and then Sample2 will be created.

Answer (score 0):

[Klaus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2142950/klaus-g%c3%bctter) comment worked fine for me.
If you are not manipulating the list, you could change the parameter type from `List<SmartSuggestionRule>` to `IEnumerable<SmartSuggestionRule>`. This allows you to pass any collection of `SmartSuggestionRule` and derived classes.

I ONLY had to do some implicit conversion, which I was not doing correctly earlier. `(List<Sample1SmartSuggestionRule>)MatchKeywordToRule(ref keywordsInput, sample1SmartSuggestionRuleObj);`

The other approach (a better one I think) doesn't involve implicit conversion:

[shingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6196568/shingo)
suggested to use generic method:
`private List<T> MatchKeywordToRule<T>(ref string keywords, List<T> rules) where T : SmartSuggestionRule`